# Crystal: detect if a dictionary insert overwrites a key, but without hashing twice

Tags: crystal-lang

What is the canonical way in Crystal to insert a key into a [Hash](https://crystal-lang.org/api/latest/Hash.html), but throw an error if the mapping did exist before. In principle, code like this:

```rb
map = Hash(String, Int32).new
if map.has_key?("foo")
  raise "Mapping already exists"
else
  map["foo"] = 42
end
```

I wondered if is it possible without hashing twice? I came up with this idea, but it is hard to read IMHO:

```rb
map = Hash(String, Int32).new
if map.put("foo", 42) {}
  raise "Mapping already exists"
end
```

(If the mapping exists, [`Map#put`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/1.1.0/Hash.html#put(key:K,value:V,&)-instance-method) returns the old value. Otherwise, the result of the block is called, which is `nil` and evaluates to `false`.)

Is there a recommended pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance wise you already arrived at the optimal solution. I would probably use the fact that block calls get inlined to rewrite it slightly:

```
def update(hash, key, value)
  hash.put(key, value) { return }
  raise "Duplicate entry"
end
```

However there's an important pitfall here: The hash still gets updated in the error condition:

```
hash = {"foo" => "bar"}
update(hash, "baz", "quux")
pp hash # => {"foo" => "bar", "baz" => "quux"}
update(hash, "foo", "hello") rescue puts "Failed updating foo" # => Failed updating foo
pp hash # => {"foo" => "hello", "baz" => "quux"}
```

https://carc.in/#/r/bn1o

Without breaking into internal APIs I don't think there's a way to avoid this. In practice a hash lookup is not very expensive, after all its a data structure optimized for looking up a value by a key. Especially since you seem to be okay with raising in your API, which is a much more expensive operation in relation. So personally I would go for something like your first example.

Comment: I think you are right that typically the extra lookup should not matter. In the use case that I had in mind, the exception path would never be taken. It would be enforcing a precondition on the fly, so I was not worried about the exception. Yet I also come the conclusion that it is not worth it to make the code harder to read. At least, with "has_key?" everyone immediately understands what is going on. Looks like the type of micro-optimization that you should rather avoid. The "update" function is a nice trick to improve readability though.

Comment: https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/8660